# Nexus server with unexpected behavior

Tags: maven, nexus

I've installed a local nexus on my computer to use it as a mirror of the numerous nexus servers that my company have.

I think it's working because if I access the following URL oin my browse:

`http://localhost:2312/repository/my_repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom`

It's show the content of the .pom file.

But when I run mvn clean install on prompt, I got the following:

`Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:2312/repository/my_repo/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom. Return code is: 504 , ReasonPhrase:Gateway Timeout.`

On my maven settings.xml I put this:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>Nexus</id>
        <name>Nexus Local</name>
        <url>http://localhost:2312/repository/my_repo/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: First is there a good reason why you have change the default port from 8081 to 2312 ? Furthermore have you checked the log file of Nexus?

Comment: I changed the default port only to avoid conflicts with another server running localy...
None is printed on log...

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup your `settings.xml` like this:

```
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```